# Excepción en 'System.FormatException' C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, dropdownlist

Tengo los siguientes métodos para eventos de `dropdownlist`, en el cual uno condiciona al otro, y así sucesivamente. Todos corren bien a excepción del último, el cual me muestra una excepción del tipo: `'System.FormatException'`:

```
protected void CarreraSeleccionada()
        {
            List<ListadoCarrera> ListadoCarrera = RespuestaLN.getInstance().ListarCarrera();
            dropCarrera.DataSource = ListadoCarrera;
            dropCarrera.DataTextField = "Nombre2";
            dropCarrera.DataValueField = "IDCampo";
            dropCarrera.DataBind();
            AreaSeleccionada();
        }

        protected void AreaSeleccionada()
        {
            int CarreraID = Convert.ToInt32(dropCarrera.SelectedValue);
            dropArea.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM area WHERE cod_carrera =" + CarreraID);
            dropArea.DataTextField = "nombre";
            dropArea.DataValueField = "cod_area";
            dropArea.DataBind();
            TemaSeleccionado();
        }

        protected void TemaSeleccionado()
        {
            int AreaID = Convert.ToInt32(dropArea.SelectedValue);
            dropTema.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM tema WHERE cod_area =" + AreaID);
            dropTema.DataTextField = "nombre";
            dropTema.DataValueField = "cod_tema";
            dropTema.DataBind();
            PreguntaSeleccionada();
        }

        protected void PreguntaSeleccionada()
        {
            int TemaID = Convert.ToInt32(dropTema.SelectedValue);
            dropPregunta.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM pregunta WHERE cod_tema =" + TemaID);
            dropPregunta.DataTextField = "pregunta";
            dropPregunta.DataValueField = "cod_pregunta";
            dropPregunta.DataBind();
        }
```

Y la línea en la que me muestra la excepción es la siguiente:

```
int TemaID = Convert.ToInt32(dropTema.SelectedValue);
```

Por si acaso, muestro los códigos de los `dropdownlist` de tema y pregunta:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>*Código de tema:</label>&nbsp;
                                        <!-- El botón para abrir el cuadro -->
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect btn-sm"
                                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miCuadroModal5">
                                        ?
                                    </button>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropTema" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>*Código de pregunta:</label>&nbsp;
                                            <!-- El botón para abrir el cuadro -->
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect btn-sm"
                                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miCuadroModal1">
                                            ?
                                        </button>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropPregunta" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Coloca un `breakpoint` en esa linea y revisa que trae `dropTema.SelectedValue` puede que este cargando algo que no es un entero.

Comment: Puedes usar también esto: `int TemaID = 0; int.TryParse(dropTema.SelectedValue, out TemaID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se esta generando porque no puede convertir el valor a entero debido al formato que tiene el `SelectedValue`, puede que lo que estés recibiendo no tenga formato de entero. Una opción para arreglar estas excepciones es utilizar `int.TryParse()`, esta función intenta convertir un valor a entero.

Si es posible la conversión te devolverá el valor en la variable indicada, sino simplemente te devolverá `0` sin generar ninguna excepción.

```
    protected void AreaSeleccionada()
    {
        int CarreraID = 0;
        int.TryParse(dropCarrera.SelectedValue, out CarreraID);
        dropArea.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM area WHERE cod_carrera =" + CarreraID);
        dropArea.DataTextField = "nombre";
        dropArea.DataValueField = "cod_area";
        dropArea.DataBind();
        TemaSeleccionado();
    }

    protected void TemaSeleccionado()
    {
        int AreaID = 0;
        int.TryParse(dropArea.SelectedValue, out AreaID);
        dropTema.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM tema WHERE cod_area =" + AreaID);
        dropTema.DataTextField = "nombre";
        dropTema.DataValueField = "cod_tema";
        dropTema.DataBind();
        PreguntaSeleccionada();
    }

    protected void PreguntaSeleccionada()
    {
        int TemaID = 0;
        int.TryParse(dropTema.SelectedValue, out TemaID);
        dropPregunta.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM pregunta WHERE cod_tema =" + TemaID);
        dropPregunta.DataTextField = "pregunta";
        dropPregunta.DataValueField = "cod_pregunta";
        dropPregunta.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, encontré otra solución también ya que como dices no me está retornando ningún valor, entonces puse un `if (dropTema.Items.Count > 0) {*dentro iría la consulta, etc*}` y ya con eso corre sin problemas.

Comment: Que bueno amigo, bueno ya sabes como evitar la excepción en un futuro mediante `TryParse()`